# Python closures and cells (closed-over values)

Tags: python, lambda, closures

What is the Python mechanism that makes it so that

```py
[lambda: x for x in range(5)][2]()
```

is 4?

What is the usual trick for binding a copy of x to each lamba expression so that the above expression will equal 2?

---

My final solution:

```py
for template, model in zip(model_templates, model_classes):
    def create_known_parameters(known_parms):
        return lambda self: [getattr(self, p.name)
                             for p in known_parms]
    model.known_parameters = create_known_parameters(template.known_parms)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
[ partial(lambda x: x, x) for x in range(5) ]
```

Or, of course, you can do it yourself:

```
[ (lambda x: (lambda: x))(x) for x in range(5) ]
```

Comment: Yes, I went with the second solution because `funtools.partial` doesn't work well when creating methods.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> [lambda x=x: x for x in range(5)][2]()
2
```

Comment: Nice answer.  The only problem with this is that "x" can still be over-ridden, so it's not exactly identical to a zero-argument lambda.

Comment: @Neil True, though you did not specify in your question that it _had_ to be a zero-argument lambda. If you want to allow for other arguments, just do like this: `lambda a, b, x=x: a*x + b`. I can't think of any situation where the overridable x would be a problem.

Comment: @NeilG, for what it's worth, I prefer this way of doing it; I see it way more often than `partial` or nested `lambda` statements; and I find it more readable. Unlike lazyr, I _can_ think of a few situations where the overridable x would be a problem, but they're pretty uncommon. (lazyr, +1)

Comment: @senderle: I agree with you for a one-off piece of code.  The problem with this method is that calling the function with one positional argument should ideally raise a `TypeError`.  This way, it will blindly work.  For a library method, that's a big enough deal to warrant doing it another way.


Like you, I find the nested lambda hard to read, so I expanded the outer lambda into a regular function definition.  (See my recent edit.)

Answer (score 3):

Since no one's answered the "what is the mechanism" part, and this surprised me when I first read it, here's a go:

This:

```
ls = [lambda: x for x in range(5)]
```

Is a bit like this:

```
ls = []
x = 0
ls.append(lambda: x)
x = 1
ls.append(lambda: x)
x = 2
ls.append(lambda: x)
x = 3
ls.append(lambda: x)
x = 4
ls.append(lambda: x)
```

Each of those lambdas has its own scope, but none of those scopes contain an `x`. So they're all going to be reading the value of `x` by looking in an outer scope, so of course they must all be referring to the same object. By the time any of them are called, the loop is done and that object is the integer `4`.

So even though these lambdas look like functions involving only immutable values, they can still be affected by side effects, because they depend on the bindings in an outer scope, and that scope can change.

You could of course further change what these lambdas return by rebinding `x`, or make them throw an error by unbinding it. In the list comprehension version though, the `x` is only bound in a private scope inside the list comprehension, so you can't mess with it (as easily).

The solution is of course to arrange things so that each lambda has an `x` in its local scope (or at least some outer scope that is not shared between the lambdas), so that they can all refer to different objects. Ways to do that have been shown in the other answers.