# Getting confused with lambda and list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, closures, list-comprehension

Read a question on stack overflow sometime back with the following syntax

```
In [1]: [lambda: x for x in range(5)][0]()
Out[1]: 4
In [2]: [lambda: x for x in range(5)][2]()
Out[2]: 4
```

But i am having a hard time to understand why exactly the output of this comes as 4,
my understanding is it always gives the last value of the list as output,

```
In [4]: [lambda: x for x in [1,5,7,3]][0]()
Out[4]: 3
```

but still not convinced how does this syntax ends up with the last value.

Would be very glad if i can get a proper explanation for this syntax

Comment: Do you think you could find that question you mentioned?  This is interesting, I would like to figure it out as well :)

Comment: `In [84]: [z() for z in (lambda: x for x in range(5))]`  
`Out[84]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

`In [85]: [z() for z in [lambda: x for x in range(5)]]`  
`Out[85]: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`   
if generator is used instead of list comprehension then also output will differ !

Comment: @ktodisco: I'm pretty sure that it's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189702/python-closures-and-cells-closed-over-values

Comment: @Neil G: Yes, This is the one.... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't really about either list comprehensions or lambdas. It's about the scoping rules in Python. Let's rewrite the list comprehension into an equivalent loop:

```
funcs = []
for x in range(5):
    def f(): return x
    funcs.append(f)
funcs[0]() # returns 4
```

Here, we can see that we successively construct functions and store them in a list. When one of these functions is called, all that happens is the value of `x` is looked up and returned. But `x` is a variable whose value changes, so the final value of `4` is what is always returned. You could even change the value of `x` after the loop, e.g.,

```
x = 32 
funcs[2]() # returns 32
```

To get the behavior you expected, Python would need to scope the `for` contents as a block; it doesn't. Usually, this isn't a problem, and is easy enough to work around.

Answer (score 4):

For a LC with n iterations, `x` is assigned elements 0 through n-1 of the source sequence. At the final iteration, `x` is assigned the last element. The point to note is that **it's always the same `x`**, and calling the function at the end returns whatever `x` held last.

Comment: can you please break the code into multiple steps so that i can understand it in a better way :)

Comment: @avasal The lambda encloses the *name* `x`, not the value of `x`. When the LC completes, you have a list of lambdas returning the value bound to name `x` - the most recent value.

Comment: if the LC completes the first and the last value is returned to lambda , i am confused why is there 5 lambda functions 
In [6]: [lambda: x for x in range(5)]
Out[6]: 
[<function <lambda> at 0x16b7ed8>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x16b7e60>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x16c10c8>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x16c1140>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x16c11b8>]

Comment: Because 5 lambdas are still created; that's what the LC is doing.

Comment: Its like `[lambda: globals().get('x') for x in [1,5,7,3,5]][3]()`

Answer (score 3):

Let me break the code for my understanding

```
In [39]: [lambda: x for x in [1,5,7,3]]
Out[39]: 
[<function <lambda> at 0x2cd1320>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x2cd12a8>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x2cd10c8>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x2cd1050>]
```

above gives the list of functions

```
In [40]: [lambda: x for x in [1,5,7,3]][1]
Out[40]: <function <lambda> at 0x2cd1488>
```

The index 1 gives 1 function from the list of functions.

Now this function will apply on x, which has always the last value of list. Thats y always gives the last value as result.

like in below code.

```
In [41]: [lambda: 2][0]()
Out[41]: 2


In [42]: alist = [1,5,7,3,4,5,6,7]
```

x for x in [1,5,7,3] is equivalent to below function f(x). 
and
lambda: x for x in [1,5,7,3] is equivalent to lambda: 3

```
In [43]: def f(x):
   ....:     for x in alist:
   ....:         pass
   ....:     return x
In [44]: print f(alist)
7
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you've run into the common loop-closure problem; i.e. the problem that a closure captures variables by reference. In this case you are capturing a variable whose value changes over time (as with all loop variables), so it has a different value when you run it than when you created it.

To accomplish what you want, you need to capture the value of the variable at the time the lambda is created. sblom suggested the solution of wrapping it in an immediately-executed function:

```
[(lambda(i): lambda: i)(x) for x in range(5)][2]()
```

Another solution that you will often see in Python is using default arguments, which will also evaluate the value at creation time:

```
[lambda i=x: i for x in range(5)][2]()
```

(it's usually written `lambda x=x: x`, but I renamed the variable for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it:

```
[(lambda(i): lambda: i)(x) for x in range(5)][2]()
```

The problem is that you're not capturing the *value* of x on each iteration of the list comprehension, you're capturing the *variable* each time through.

Comment: i don't need to fix this i need to understand what's going on in there :)

Comment: I think OP's question is to understand how python interprets when he doesn't capture the value of `x`. :)